# TransientObjectException on nullable property in Grails

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, nullable

I have the following entity

```
class Thesis extends Article {
   String description
   Topic topic
   User assignee
   User supervisor
   ...
   static constraints = {
       supervisor nullable: true
   ...
      supervisor validator: {supervisor ->
         if (supervisor?.id != null && !User.get(supervisor.id)) {
            'not.found'
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Creating and saving new instance with no supervisor work just fine.

However when I try to remove (set to null) supervisor from existing Thesis instance I end up with TransientObjectException. I'm probably missing something about data binding because if I don't bind form data to thesisInstance and simply just set "supervisor" property to null it will get saved with no issues.

```
def thesisInstance = Thesis.get(id)
thesisInstance.properties = params.thesis
if (thesisInstance.supervisorId == null){
   thesisInstance.supervisor = null
}
thesisInstance.save()
```

EDIT: params.thesis map looks like this (disclaimer: these are dummy data)

```
thesis.tags.title: ruby
thesis.version: 7
thesis.topic.id: 13
thesis.supervisor.id: 
thesis.status: FINISHED
thesis.id: 18
thesis.title: Implementation of Ruby Killing Machine
thesis.type: BACHELOR
thesis.assignee.fullName: Somebody
thesis.university.id: 1
thesis.grade: A
thesis.supervisor.fullName: 
thesis.thesisAbstract: Implementation of Ruby Killing Machine that will kill people that are filled in an HTML form.
thesis.description: Implementation of Ruby Killing Machine that will kill people that are filled in an HTML form.
thesis.assignee.id: 4
```

As you can see thesis.supervisor.id is not populated and consequently thesisInstance.supervisor is set to new User instance witthout ID. Thus the need for "thesisInstance.supervisor = null"

I've found exactly same problem on  [1] but it's unanswered.

[1] http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Data-Binding-and-Null-ifying-problems-in-G1-2-0-td1339929.html

Comment: is this a typo? : thesisInstance.supervisorId.  You don't have a supervisorId property on Thesis.

Comment: @Gregg You can access the `id` of a domain class as such. `thesisInstance.supervisorId` is same as `thesisInstance.supervisor.id`. This is an additional functionality of domain class. ;)

Comment: @dmahapatro Does this trick work for you from a unit test? I get `no such property` error from a unit test even though it works with `run-app`.

Comment: @zoran119 No you won't get that flexibility in unit test. They are isolated and use mocking api. But you can very well get that functionality in Integration Tests. Test it and enjoy. :)

Comment: Are you sure it is complaining about supervisor? How does `params.thesis` look like?

Comment: I've added params map overview in the question, see EDIT part

Comment: And yes, I am pretty sure it is complaining about supervisor, because if I don't touch it there is no exception